# h1 reads twice in iOS voiceover

Tags: ios, vue.js, voiceover

when using voiceover on iOS on a specific h1 template it reads the heading out twice, once by hovering slightly over where the header is and once when it's actually selected the heading. I only want it to read once, what do you think might be causing it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnxTW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syA4i.png)

Attached are two images of the two things it selects to read it twice when doing voiceover and this is the template:

```
<template>
  <h1 :key="titleKey"
      ref="AppHeader"
      :class="[cssClass, 'break']"
      tabindex="-1">
    <span v-if="caption"
          :key="caption"
          :class="[captionSizeCss, 'caption--top']"
          data-purpose="header-caption">
      {{ caption }}
    </span>
    <slot/>
  </h1>
</template>
<script>
import CaptionSize from '@/lib/caption-size';
import { EventBus, FOCUS_APP_TITLE } from '@/services/event-bus';

export default {
  name: 'PageTitle',
  props: {
    cssClass: {
      type: String,
      default: 'u-margin-top-3 u-margin-bottom-7 u-padding-top-3',
    },
    titleKey: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
    caption: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
    captionSize: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    captionSizeCss() {
      if (this.captionSize) {
        return this.captionSize;
      }
      return CaptionSize.Large;
    },
  },
  beforeMount() {
    EventBus.$on(FOCUS_APP_TITLE, this.focusAppHeader);
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    EventBus.$off(FOCUS_APP_TITLE, this.focusAppHeader);
  },
  updated() {
    this.focusAppHeader();
  },
  mounted() {
    this.focusAppHeader();
  },
  methods: {
    focusAppHeader() {
      if (document.activeElement !== null) {
        document.activeElement.blur();
      }
      this.$refs.AppHeader.focus();
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "@/style/custom/break";
</style>
```

I've tried to change the aria-hidden properties and the tab index and they either make it not get read out at all or don't change anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "hover". You mentioned iOS so you're not using a mouse.  Also, can you post the HTML that is generated?  That is, the code that the browser actually renders?  Then I can copy/paste that to my ios device and try VoiceOver.